# Bootstrap - I need to zoom image on the mouse hover, but keep its original size

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, hover, overflow

I am trying to create a bootstrap grid with images with some padding, which are zoomed in on hover. The problem is that even after I set overflow to "hidden", they keep blocking the padding line I set - padding is set in the same element and for some reason they override it. For example, when I hover over the left image, it grows a bit and blocks the vertical white line in the middle. How can I force the css to respect the padding?

My html

```html
   <div class="row" style="height:100%">
 <div class="col-md-6 img-hover" style="padding-right:3px;height:100%;overflow:hidden;">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="Images/image.jpg")" style="overflow: hidden" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%; padding-right: 3px;">
            <div class="row">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="/Images/image2.jpg")" />
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="padding-top:3px;height:100%">
                <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0px;  padding-right: 3px">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="/Images/image3.jpg")" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0px;  padding-right: 3px">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="/Images/image3.jpg")" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My css:

```
.img-hover img {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease; /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all .3s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all .3s ease;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.img-hover img:hover {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1.20); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.10); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.10); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:translatZ(0) scale(1.10); /* Opera */
    transform:translatZ(0) scale(1.10);
}
```

And this is the image I have. What changes should I do so the zoomed image stops blocking the padding line? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `overflow: hidden` property on `<div>` block that is containing the `<img>`. And on `:hover` use `transform: scale(x)` property.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.grid-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first-row {
  display: flex;
}

.grid {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.one, .two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.three {
  width: 202px;
  height: 100px;
}

.grid:hover img {
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: all .2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-box">
  <div class="first-row">
    <div class="grid one">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid two">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid three">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/202x100" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, yes, it helped a bit. The main issue I had was that I was using padding property to separate images and I should have used white border - it isnt covered during zoom/